# Java: Sorting Comparison method violates its general contract

Tags: java, comparison

Below is the compare method of my comparator. I am not sure what is wrong.

I would like result in below formate.

**Data**: 1,3,0,1,0,4,6

**Result**: 1,1,3,4,6,0,0

Any help will be greatly appreciated

```
            Comparator<Test> sortOrder = new Comparator<Test>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Test d1, Test d2) {
                Integer o1 = new Integer(d1.getVal() == null ? 0 : d1.getVal());
                Integer o2 = new Integer(d2.getVal() == null ? 0 : d2.getVal());
                if (o1 == 0) {
                    return 1;
                }
                if (o2 == 0) {
                    return -1;
                }
                return o1.compareTo(o2);
            }
        };

        Set<Test> result = tests.stream().sorted(sortOrder).collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedHashSet::new));
```

Below is my exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!
   at java.util.TimSort.mergeLo(TimSort.java:777)
   at java.util.TimSort.mergeAt(TimSort.java:514)
   at java.util.TimSort.mergeCollapse(TimSort.java:441)
   at java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:245)
   at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1512)
   at java.util.stream.SortedOps$SizedRefSortingSink.end(SortedOps.java:348)
   at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:482)
   at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
   at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
   at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
   at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499)
```

Comment: Just for the record: please be more diligent *before* putting up your code. Always really copy in from your editor, right before you ran it. And always have example data within the question; ideally people should be able to copy/paste your input into their IDE, run code, and see your results. Coming in and changing typos and other flaws "on the fly" within questions is really not an appreciated practice. Your content should be **ready** when putting up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Beyond the `d1.getVal()` appearing twice typo (which may or may not exist in your actual code), you are violating the contract of `Comparator`'s `compare` method, since `sgn(compare(x,y)) != -sgn(compare(y,x))` if `getVal()` is `0` for both of the compared `Test` instances `x` and `y`.

You should either return `0` in this case or use another field to compare the two instances.

From the Javadoc:

> The implementor must ensure that sgn(compare(x, y)) ==-sgn(compare(y, x)) for all x and y.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I corrected my question. Please review now

Comment: @vikas my answer still applies. If both o1 and o2 are 0, you should probably return 0 (not 1 and not -1).